# Is this sentence using the correct tense?

Tags: gramática

Is this sentence using the correct tense?

> Pues adivino si tuviera la oportunidad me gustaría ir Hawái, puesto
>   que nadaría en el mar bonito y porque por lo visto haría mucho sol y
>   calor que me gustan. Por lo tanto, sé que sería una experiencia
>   mágica, pero itendré que ganar a la lotería.

Answer (score 3):

> Creo que si tuviera la oportunidad de ir a Hawái, nadaría en el mar
>   bonito. Me encanta mucho el sol y calor, por lo que sería una
>   experiencia mágica. Pero para viajar tendría que ganarme la lotería.

The last sentence should be conditional because is something subjective and non-determinative. You cannot win the lottery for sure. You could win but you couldn't know.

I re-arranged your paragraph, I hope you like it. If not, as I told you the last part should be **tendría** instead of **tendré**

I think you are translating the first part **Pues adivino** from **Well I guess** or maybe **Well I think**. You can say directly **Creo que** and give later your arguments. That way it would sound better for hispanics.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo *(I guess you meant guess)* que...ir a Hawai, puesto que podría nadar en el ese mar tan bonito, en un clima caluroso y bajo el sol que tanto me gusta. Sería una experiencia mágica, pero tendría que ganar la lotería para hacerla realidad.

tell me if you want comments on what I've corrected. ;)